# git trying to write a file on a push that was deleted

Tags: git, github, terminal

I have be working on this repo for a long time and all of a sudden I ran into a problem.  I realized I had a 350 meg .csv file.  My normal procedure to push to to github was:

```
git add .
git commit -m "some message"
git push
```

When I realized it was starting to write a large file I looked at saw it was that large .csv "shifts.csv".  So I deleted it and I went

```
git rm shifts.csv
```

I rewent through the process of adding, committing and pushing and it was still trying to write this large file on a push after having deleted it.  Googling for a solution I can't find one.

Comment: I assume you cancelled the push while it was uploading?

Comment: First time I decided to try and let it run, but github doesnt allow files over 100 megs, so that fail.  Now when I try and push I just ctrl^c when I see it is still trying to write it.

Comment: I would make a backup of your changes and perform a `git reset --hard` to reset your commit to your `HEAD`, reapply your changes then commit+push again without your 300mb file.

Comment: I tried that but it seems the last commit was after i tried to `git rm shifts.csv` but on push it still is trying to write that large file

Comment: Did you `--amend` the commit with the large file in it? Or did you just add another commit on top of that one which removes the file? If you're not sure, run `git log --oneline --graph --decorate -15` and paste the output in your question so we can see what's going on.

Comment: I just ended up going into the `git log` to an older copy, `git reset -b` to there, added in my new files.  Added, committed and pushed.

Answer (score 2):

Git is probably still trying to push the file to your remote repo, because although

```
git rm shifts.csv
git commit
```

removes the file from the current and future state of your source code, ***it still exists in the repository history***, in earlier commits, and therefore when you push, Git has to push ***all of your history*** to your remote still, including the commits with the file in it, because it's still part of your earlier history.

You have to somehow completely erase the file from the history of your repo, as if it never existed at any point in time. If the commit in which the file was created isn't too far back in your history, you could possibly use an interactive rebase to remove it, or do a hard reset if you don't mind losing work.

However, if the commit is buried far back in your history, then your only practical option is probably to erase the file from your history using `git filter-branch`.